# Create object on heap when using class templates

Tags: c++, templates, heap-memory

I want to do this:

```
Array<int>* arr = new Array();
```

But I keep getting an error: Argument list for class "Array" is missing.
Is it not possible to create this on the heap? I haven't seen any code that seems to do this.

I've tried another way as well where I use the code:

```
Array<int>* arr;
```

and then tried to print the contents of the array, but it was giving me the error that it hadn't been instantiated yet. If I cannot create it on the heap, how am I suppose to instantiate it dynamically. I don't know what the user will want to put into it, after all.

Here's all my code:

**Array.h**

```
#ifndef _ARRAY_H_
#define _ARRAY_H_

#include <cstring>          // for size_t definition

/**
 * @class Array
 *
 * Basic implementation of a standard array class for chars.
 */
template <typename T>
class Array 
{
    public:
        /// Type definition of the element type.
        typedef T type;

        /// Default constructor.
        Array (void);


    private:
        /// Pointer to the actual data.
        T* data_;

        /// Current size of the array.
        size_t cur_size_;

        /// Maximum size of the array.
        size_t max_size_;
};

#include "Array.inl"
//#include "Array.cpp"

#endif   // !defined _ARRAY_H_
```

**Array.cpp**

```
#include <stdexcept>         // for std::out_of_bounds exception
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.h"

#define MAX_SIZE_ 20

//
// Array
// Default Constructor 
template <typename T>
Array <T>::Array (void)
    :data_(new T[MAX_SIZE_]),
    cur_size_(0),
    max_size_(MAX_SIZE_)
{   }
```

**Array.inl**

```
//
// size
//
template <typename T>
inline
size_t Array <T>::size(void) const
{
    return this->cur_size_;
}

//
// max_size
//
template <typename T>
inline
size_t Array <T>::max_size(void) const
{
    return this->max_size_;
}
```

**driver.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
//#include "Array_Base.h"
#include "Array.h"

int main(void)
{
    Array<int>* arr = new Array();
    std::cout << "Max size of array is: " << arr->max_size() << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. `Array<int>* arr = new Array();` should be `Array<int>* arr = new Array<int>();` or, simpler, `auto arr = new Array<int>();`.

Comment: `#define _ARRAY_H_` That is a reserved identifier. By defining it, your program will have undefined behaviour. You should use another header guard.

Comment: Why not just use `Array<int> arr;`?

Answer (score 2):

Because the class is a template class, just `Array` isn't a full type.  You need to include the template type.  And there's no need for the empty parentheses at the end.

```
Array<int>* arr = new Array<int>;
```

Comment: We would also need size i.e. 

Array<int, size>* arr new = Array<int, size>;

Comment: @UnSat I'm looking at the class definition and there's only one template parameter. Maybe it needs a second one, but that wasn't part of the question.